# Mobile Site Re-Direct because of CSS Problems?

Tags: css, mobile, subdomain, html

I recently made a website where I edited the containers of the product page in order to make the image bigger as WooCommerce's image enlargement options weren't working. Because of this however, the mobile page is not optimized.

My website is the following: www.ininkk.com

I was wondering what I should do in order to combat this inefficiency? I tried uploading a backup of the site onto a sub-domain but the package size was too large for upload when using the BackupBuddy and Duplicator plugins.

I'm at my wit's end here. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `not optimized`? is it because the images are too large? or is there something else?

Answer (score 0):

Google Insights shows that you need to:

- compress Javascript code
- compress images
- compress CSS
- gzip this file: http://ininkk.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=vanajax_enqueue_custom_style_via_ajax&ver=1.0.0.0

And there's way too many .css files in this project. You need to make one big file of CSS of everything and compress that.

These options will let you score better on Google Insights and also increase your website's loading speed.